# UISearchBar width animation and AutoLayout

Tags: ios, animation, uisearchbar, autolayout

I have had a massive amount of problems trying to animate the UISearchBar to simply expand when editing, so I thought I would provide a solution to anyone else who has had to suffer this problem.

There are already [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636367/cant-animate-the-frame-or-bounds-of-a-uisearchbar) in animating a UISearchBar and problems increase further when mixing that with the iOS AutoLayout. If you have had the same issues then the I have posted the solution below. It may not be perfect but it does work.

Comment: This is how to achieve this in swift http://stackoverflow.com/a/29565613/2683201

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial and error I got it to work by turning the AutoLayout functionality off in the xib and then using the Animation method below:

```
+(CAAnimationGroup *)changeView:(UIView *)view frameTo:(CGRect)frame{
CGRect oldFrame = view.frame;

// /2.0 because size animation occurs from the anchor point which is set to (0.5,0.5) by default
CGPoint oldOrigin = CGPointMake(oldFrame.origin.x+oldFrame.size.width/2.0, oldFrame.origin.y+oldFrame.size.height/2.0);
CGPoint newOrigin = CGPointMake(frame.origin.x+frame.size.width/2.0, frame.origin.y+frame.size.height/2.0);

CABasicAnimation *positionAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];

positionAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:oldOrigin];
positionAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:newOrigin];
view.layer.position = newOrigin;

CABasicAnimation *sizeAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds"];

sizeAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:oldFrame];
sizeAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:frame];
view.layer.bounds = frame;

CAAnimationGroup *frameChangeAnimationGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];

frameChangeAnimationGroup.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
frameChangeAnimationGroup.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:positionAnimation,sizeAnimation, nil];

[view.layer addAnimation:frameChangeAnimationGroup forKey:@"frame"];

return frameChangeAnimationGroup;}
```

I hope this helps and saves people some of the pain I had to go through.